# Using Jump Flooding Alghorithm for pathfinding?

Tags: shaders, path-finding

I am creating a distance-to-river texture. I am using the Jump-Flood Alghorithm in a compute shader to do this using simple distance() and it works well. See code below.
I want to augment this by adding blockers/walls so raw distance-to-seed might be blocked by pixels inbetween. I need to adapt it to a more pathfinding alghorithm.

Is this possible to do with JFA? Or do I need some other solution?

```
cbuffer JFAConstants : register( CBUFFER_REGISTER_EXTRA )
{
    int2 gSampleOffset;
}

RWTexture2D<uint2> gJumpFloodRiverMap : register( UAV_REGISTER_0 );

void UpdateClosest( inout int2 currentValue, int2 currentTexcoord, int2 jumpTexcoord )
{
    int2 jumpValue = gJumpFloodRiverMap[ jumpTexcoord ];
    if ( IsZero( jumpValue ) )
    {
        return;
    }

    float jumpDistance = distance( (float2)currentTexcoord, (float2)jumpValue );
    if ( IsZero( currentValue ) )
    {
        gJumpFloodRiverMap[ currentTexcoord ] = jumpValue;
        currentValue = jumpValue;
        return;
    }

    float currentDistance = distance( (float2)currentTexcoord, (float2)currentValue );
    if ( jumpDistance < currentDistance )
    {
        gJumpFloodRiverMap[ currentTexcoord ] = jumpValue;
        currentValue = jumpValue;
    }
}

[numthreads(TERRAIN_NORMAL_THREADS_AXIS, TERRAIN_NORMAL_THREADS_AXIS, 1)]
void cs_main(uint3 groupID : SV_GroupID, uint3 dispatchTID : SV_DispatchThreadID, uint3 groupTID : SV_GroupThreadID, uint groupIndex : SV_GroupIndex)
{
    int2 texCoord = dispatchTID.xy;
    int2 currentValue = gJumpFloodRiverMap[ texCoord ];

    int2 texCoordT = texCoord + int2( 0, gSampleOffset.y );
    int2 texCoordTR = texCoord + gSampleOffset;
    int2 texCoordR = texCoord + int2( gSampleOffset.x, 0 );
    int2 texCoordBR = texCoord + int2( gSampleOffset.x, -gSampleOffset.y );
    int2 texCoordB = texCoord + int2( 0, -gSampleOffset.y );
    int2 texCoordBL = texCoord - gSampleOffset;
    int2 texCoordL = texCoord + int2( -gSampleOffset.x, 0 );
    int2 texCoordTL = texCoord + int2( -gSampleOffset.x, gSampleOffset.y );

    UpdateClosest( currentValue, texCoord, texCoordT );
    UpdateClosest( currentValue, texCoord, texCoordTR );
    UpdateClosest( currentValue, texCoord, texCoordR );
    UpdateClosest( currentValue, texCoord, texCoordBR );
    UpdateClosest( currentValue, texCoord, texCoordB );
    UpdateClosest( currentValue, texCoord, texCoordBL );
    UpdateClosest( currentValue, texCoord, texCoordL );
    UpdateClosest( currentValue, texCoord, texCoordTL );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "adapt it to a more pathfinding alghorithm"?

Comment: by adding "walled off pixels" I couldn't use distance() anymore right since that might intersect with them?